# I want to multiply two different arrays values that is coming through inputs

Tags: php

I have some inputs which are accepting arrays values which are dynamically generated via javascript so the user can add more item name, item price, and item quantity and sending it to process via $_POST

Like this -----

```
<input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="item_name" placeholder="Item Name">

<input type="text" name="item_price[]" id="item_price" placeholder="Item Price">

<input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
```

I just want to multiply my each and every item_price to my item_quantity
like -----

if i have $item_price = 400; and $quantity = 3;

then I want $t = $item_price * $quantity for each and every values that i get from users.

but I don't understand how can I iterate through all item price and quantity and multiply each of them.

please help me solve it this is the only part where I am stuck and spent my whole day to figure out tried different methods but getting wrong values.

Here is my PHP code

```
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_price = $_POST['item_price'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

foreach ($item_name as $key => $i_n) {

       echo $i_n."<br>";
   }

foreach ($item_price as $key => $i_p) {

       echo $i_p."<br>";
   }

 foreach ($quantity as $key => $q) {

       echo $q."<br>";
   }

// I am outputting item name, item price,  quantity just to check
```

Comment: you only show one item, whats the post array structure for multiple items?

Comment: <input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="item_name" placeholder="Item Name">

Comment: <input type="text" name="item_price[]" id="item_price" placeholder="Item Price">

Comment: <input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity">

Comment: using field names such as `items[0][name]` + `items[0][quantity]` and `items[1][name]` + `items[1][quantity]` will allow you to group your data in a more meaningful way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop over one set and match the key to the others.

```
foreach ($item_name as $key => $value) {
    echo $item_name[$key].', '.
         $item_price[$key].', '.
         $quantity[$key]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much rest of the work I can do thanks for helping me out. can u tell me, was my question noob?